# Write data to columns in SQL Server table dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `.csv` file with around 200 columns and the order of columns changes all the time. I want to read each row from the file, identify the corresponding column names in the database, and write data to the table accordingly.

For this I can use a simple switch case checking for the name of column. Since there are 200 columns, I'm wondering if there is any other way to do it.

Example:

```
    public void ColName(string str, Type a)
     {
       SampleTableName obj = new SampleTableName();
       obj."str" = a;
       connection.AddSampleTableName(obj);
       connection.savechanges();
     }

    /* SampleTableName has columns: [Name, Age] */
    ColName("Name","XYZ");
    Output:
    Name Age
    XYZ  NULL
```

Any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe consider serialize each record to JSON, and store them in a TEXT field in the DB.

Comment: Lot of fields in the file have numbers. Some of them are strings, datetimes, integers and floats. Does your idea still work? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary` instead of a `switch` statement

Comment: Yes, but I still have to specify all the 200 cases(values) for each key. Time complexity is not an issue in this case.

Comment: I think so. Especially the csv has 200 columns. Even creating a table with 200 columns sounds like a lot of work to me. Not to mention you will have to maintain the structure of this table.

To me it is easier to have a table with two columns (Id, Text), and store your CSV in the Text column in format of JSON or XML.

Comment: Yeah I already have a table with the said number of columns, this data is purely for displaying purposes. and may be some times find mean, SD that kind of stuff. If [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm) is what you are talking about, it seems like it may work.

Comment: @CSK, yup, that's exactly what I am talking about. I was gonna mention Newton.JSON but you found it yourself. 

One step further, you could ditch the SQL Database, use a NoSQL solution (e.g. CouchBase) as your data store. You don't need a table with 200 columns.

Comment: I have to again load this data from database to a web page and the total application is in ASP.Net. Is it going to get more complex if I use CouchDB?

Comment: Importing a CSV is a *very* simple job and SQL Server even has a wizard for this (Import Data). This can generate an SSIS package that you can open and edit with the Sql Server Database Tools, to add transformations etc. Using Json doesn't offer anything but it *will* prevent you from querying the data.

Comment: PS the wizard will match columns name-for-name although you can change the mappings. Same goes when you work with SSDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple for maintenance purpose, I went with a switch case *sigh*. However, I wrote a small script to add all those fields values to the table object.

Answer (score 0):

If the column names are the same you can use SqlBulkCopy and add a list of Column Mappings. The order doesn't matter, as long as the DataTable name is set.

```
DataTable table = CreateTable(rows);
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
    foreach (var col in table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>())
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(
            new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName));
    }
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600; // in seconds
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "<tableName>";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

If the column names are no the same, a dictionary to lookup the different names could be used.